# Access Defined Vue Components from the Global Scope

Tags: javascript, scope, vue.js

Using Vue.js, is it possible to access an instantiated Vue.js component object from the global JavaScript scope?  Or do Vue's internals instantiate the objects in such a way that they're not accessible?

i.e. I have code that defines a component

```
Vue.component('component-name', {
   /*...*/
});
```

and then a tag uses that component

```
<component-name>
    /* can user templates with component objects vars {{foo}}
</component-name>
```

Vue's template rendering code is, ultimately, accessing a JavaScript object.  Is there a way for me, via code, to peek at that instantiated Vue component object?  Something like

```
var theComponent = getInstantiatedComponent('component-name');
```

I'm aware of the Vue.js Chrome debugger – but I'd like to know if it's possible to access these objects *via code*, and what that syntax is (and my Chrome Plugins skills are too weak to poke at what they're doing in the debugger plugin).

Comment: What are you looking for? In most of the lifecycle events you can examine `this` and will see the component itself.

Comment: @BertEvans thank you for your attention!  If my context helps: I work on developer tooling.  I'm not looking for anything other than what I say I'm looking for -- a way to access the instantiated component objects from the global javascript scope.

Comment: From the global scope you can capture the result of the Vue constructor (`const app = new Vue(...)`), and from there you can dig into the complete component tree, though it's not well documented.

Comment: @BertEvans Thanks again -- but I'm looking to access this information at runtime, and in applications where I don't control instantiation of the vue constructor. Useful information regardless!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what the Vue Dev Tools are doing is scanning the DOM to find root level instances of Vue.

See the scan function [here](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-devtools/blob/d43253ff057ab4f933812f8fcdc750ba5e6db9ef/src/backend/index.js#L105). Essentially it looks through the elements on the page trying to find elements with the property `__vue__`. From there it makes a couple decisions to determine whether it is a root instance.

Once you have a root, you should be able to traverse its properties (like `$children`) to find instances of components.

Answer (score 3):

Any globally registered Vue component can be accessed from any other component using :

```
this.$options.components.MyComponent
```

or :

```
this.$options.components['MyComponent']
```

If MyComponent is not found from inside the current component, JS will search through the prototype chain until he finds it (or not), the last step being the root Vue instance prototype where all global components are registered.